# How To Turn Off Keyboard Backlight on MacBook Pro 2021?

Tags: macbook-pro

The 2021 14/16 inch MBP's don't have the Touch Bar nor the function keys dedicated to adjusting keyboard light. Has anyone figured out how to manually turn it off completely if I find it distracting?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can do it from the [Control Centre](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/mac-help/mchl50f94f8f/mac) — the new icon in the menu bar that looks like two sliders. When you click on that, it shows a dropdown with several panes:

[image: snapshot of the Control Centre on macOS 12.1 Monterey]

One of the small panes says ‘Keyboard Brightness’: click on that, and it shows a slider that you can drag from full brightness all the way down to none:

[image: snapshot of the Keyboard Brightness pane]

Note that in System Preferences, the ‘Keyboard’ tab of the ‘Keyboard’ pane has a few options related to the keyboard backlight that you might want to check: in particular, the backlight can be turned off after anything from 5 seconds to 5 minutes of inactivity.

Comment: This is not the case anymore sadly, only a tile saying "Stage Manager" instead

Answer (score 5):

In case the icon is missing, you can add it from the Control Centre pane in the System Settings. Just toggle the 'Show in Control Centre' switch.

[image: screenshot of System settings]

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/331658)